# How Would I Make An Object Jump And Fall Onto The Player Location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a bit new to unity but I was wondering ***how would I make this object jump and then fall onto the player location*** just like how I showed in this picture I would like to make this rock jump and then fall towards the player like a gravity and does the that curve I'm not sure if I explained it well enough but thank you ! any help is appericiate it[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rigidbody or Rigidbody2D for your player, you can do this:

1. Add force to jump

You can just refer to the manual https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

2. Detect whether it is fall or jumping

Detect the rigidbody's velocity value. You can refer to this link https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-detect-if-the-player-is-falling.875857/

3. Make it move towards the (crown?)

If you have Rigidbody in your Gameobject, You can use whether [Add Force](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) or [MoveTowrads](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html). In case you are using Move Towards, make sure you put it Inisde Update() function